# using the localstorage to save the state of the el li elements on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to save the state of the li clicked so on page load, it should keep that item opened

here is my html

```
<div class="nav nav-list categories" id="left-side">
   <ul class="left-menu">
      <li class="has-child">
         <a href="javascript:;">Men</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="59_73"><a href="productlist.php?category=59&amp;secondary=73">Gowns 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="59_77"><a href="productlist.php?category=59&amp;secondary=77">Readymade suits 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
              
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-child">
         <a href="javascript:;">Women</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="54_74"><a href="productlist.php?category=54&amp;secondary=74">Blouses 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="54_76"><a href="productlist.php?category=54&amp;secondary=76">Bridal Lenghas 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="54_70"><a href="productlist.php?category=54&amp;secondary=70">Fancy Duppata's 
                  (4) 
                  </a>
               </li>

            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-child">
         <a href="javascript:;">Girls Wear (1 - 12)</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="57_74"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=74">Blouses 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_76"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=76">Bridal Lenghas 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_70"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=70">Fancy Duppata's 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_73"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=73">Gowns 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_72"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=72">Grad Dresses 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               
               <li id="57_79"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=79">Without Stitches Suits 
                  (4) 
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-child">
         <a href="javascript:;">Boys Wear</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="60_73"><a href="productlist.php?category=60&amp;secondary=73">Gowns 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="60_77"><a href="productlist.php?category=60&amp;secondary=77">Readymade suits 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="60_112"><a href="productlist.php?category=60&amp;secondary=112">Pasmina Suits 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and this my javascript code which i am trying to do, i tried myself but it is setting up the value but as undefined, so the attr id is not stored as the key, something is messed up.

```
$(document).on('click', '.left-menu > li', function() {
    let self = $(this);
    var subMenu = self.find(".left-sub-menu");
    if (subMenu.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var list = self.find(".list");
    if (subMenu.hasClass('open')) {
        subMenu.removeClass('open');
        subMenu.height(0);
        self.removeClass('opened')
    } else {
        $('.left-menu > li').removeClass('opened')
        $('.left-sub-menu').removeClass('open').height(0);
        self.addClass('opened')
        subMenu.addClass('open');
        let h = list.outerHeight(true);
        subMenu.height(h > 250 ? 250 : h);
        window.localStorage.setItem($('.left-menu > li').attr('id'),"Open");
    }
});
```

but i see it undefined in the local storage

can anyone guide me how can i fix it

Thanks

Comment: Try `console.log($('.left-menu > li').attr('id'))` and make sure it's what you expected.  Then, try `console.log(self.id)`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```js
window.localStorage.setItem($('.left-menu > li').attr('id'),"Open");
```

Here, you are saying, with `$('.left-menu > li').attr('id')`:

1. Get all elements that match `.left-menu > li`
2. Get the `id` attribute value of the first element in this list.

The first element that matches `.left-menu > li` would be this element:

```html
<div class="nav nav-list categories" id="left-side">
   <ul class="left-menu">
      <li class="has-child">
```

As you should be able to see, this has no `id` attribute and thus will return `undefined` from the `.attr('id')` call.

You could look at giving unique `id` attributes to all elements that match `.left-menu > li` and then reference the element that is clicked in the click handler when saving the ID into `localStorage`. Something like:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.left-menu > li', function() {
    let self = $(this);
    var subMenu = self.find(".left-sub-menu");
    if (subMenu.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var list = self.find(".list");
    if (subMenu.hasClass('open')) {
        subMenu.removeClass('open');
        subMenu.height(0);
        self.removeClass('opened')
    } else {
        $('.left-menu > li').removeClass('opened')
        $('.left-sub-menu').removeClass('open').height(0);
        self.addClass('opened')
        subMenu.addClass('open');
        let h = list.outerHeight(true);
        subMenu.height(h > 250 ? 250 : h);
        
        // Console log to confirm working ID for illustrative purposes only,
        // since we cannot read localStorage in StackOverflow's sandbox.
        console.log(self.attr('id'));

        window.localStorage.setItem(self.attr('id'),"Open");
    }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="nav nav-list categories" id="left-side">
   <ul class="left-menu">
      <li class="has-child" id="item-1">
         <a href="javascript:;">Men</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="59_73"><a href="productlist.php?category=59&amp;secondary=73">Gowns 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="59_77"><a href="productlist.php?category=59&amp;secondary=77">Readymade suits 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
              
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-child" id="item-2">
         <a href="javascript:;">Women</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="54_74"><a href="productlist.php?category=54&amp;secondary=74">Blouses 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="54_76"><a href="productlist.php?category=54&amp;secondary=76">Bridal Lenghas 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="54_70"><a href="productlist.php?category=54&amp;secondary=70">Fancy Duppata's 
                  (4) 
                  </a>
               </li>

            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-child" id="item-3">
         <a href="javascript:;">Girls Wear (1 - 12)</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="57_74"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=74">Blouses 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_76"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=76">Bridal Lenghas 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_70"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=70">Fancy Duppata's 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_73"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=73">Gowns 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="57_72"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=72">Grad Dresses 
                  (2) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               
               <li id="57_79"><a href="productlist.php?category=57&amp;secondary=79">Without Stitches Suits 
                  (4) 
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-child" id="item-4">
         <a href="javascript:;">Boys Wear</a> 
         <div class="left-sub-menu">
            <ul class="list">
               <li id="60_73"><a href="productlist.php?category=60&amp;secondary=73">Gowns 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="60_77"><a href="productlist.php?category=60&amp;secondary=77">Readymade suits 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li id="60_112"><a href="productlist.php?category=60&amp;secondary=112">Pasmina Suits 
                  (1) 
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```